# Web accessibility language detection with Voiceover

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

How does Voiceover detect language and how can I make it "speak" the same language throughout a website?

My computer is in English, I am working on a website that offers various localizations.
Voiceover can very well read `<p>` or `<span>` elements in that current local (not English) but when I focus on a `<button>` element, it doesn't detect the language and reads everything in English, which doesn't make sense because the text is not in English. I have the `lang` attribute set in `<html>` but it doesn't seem to help. I've even added the lang attribute to the button, but still nothing.

I have tried adding a `<p>` element inside of a `<button>` but it still does the same thing.

Is that just how Voiceover works or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You wrote **"reads everything in English"** but then you put **"the text is not in English"** - please clarify **exactly** what is happening. You've worded it as though it's _translating_ non-English text to English.

Comment: it reads it as it was written in english

Comment: _Voiceover_ is Apple-specific. Is this Voiceover for iOS or Voiceover for macOS? What browser are you using? What happens when you use a non-Apple browser or non-Apple platform?

Comment: For MacOS, it does the same thing in all the browsers I've tested it in. Safari, Chrome and Firefox. I don't have access to another screen reader. my question is specific to voiceover as the title suggests

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a limitation of Voiceover? Are you aware of any websites where Voiceover reads other languages correctly? I found some forum-threads on the web where Apple users are complaining that Voiceover on iOS reads multiple languages fine but on macOS it doesn't, e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7970381

Comment: do the buttons have `aria-label`, `aria-labelledby` etc. by any chance?

Comment: I'm also starting to think it is a voiceover limitation.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie yes, they do, I have tried all of them but the end result is the same

Comment: If it has an `aria-label` then that is what gets read out, so if that is in English then it will be read in English, even if the button text is not.

Comment: GrahamRitchie *The text is not in English*. Not the aria label or the text on the buttons, no English at all used in the website. But VoiceOver reads it as if they were written in English. This issue only occurs in the buttons and in no other element. Anyway, seems to be a VoiceOver issue. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing it turns out to be a VoiceOver issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue, did you find a solution? Is this a documented limitation of Voice Over? Do you have a link to that documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the language manually in the System Settings?

Go to System Settings > Accessibility > Voice Over > "Open Voice Over Utility" > Speech > Click "+" button on the bottom to add a new language.

[image: screenshot of the settings window]

Answer (score 0):

Although some screen readers can automatically detect the language of text, this can be unreliable. To ensure proper language identification for user agents, it's recommended to use the `lang` attribute.

In VoiceOver on MacOS, for the text of a button to be read in a language different from that of the page, add the `lang` attribute to the button:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    This is a page in English
    <button lang="fr">Le texte de ce bouton est en français</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Additionally the voice for the target language needs to be installed in VoiceOver utility > Speech > Voices.